# AWS Snapshots As Only Backup

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is only using AWS snapshots as a backup solution viable. I've a a few ELBs, EC2s, S3 buckets and RDS databases.

They are all in the one AZ so I don't have multi AZ fail over. What's the best solution? I'm used to the traditional backup solution file system snapshots and backup to tape weekly, monthly, yearly and then rotating them but what's the best solution for cloud only.

Just started a new job and it's all cloud based.

Comment: I would never trust all my data to one provider. I back up my data from AWS to another cloud, it's relatively simple. My time to recover would be measured in days, but that suits my RTO/RPO. You need to work out how important your systems and data are and do a risk analysis. Do you need data backed up? System images? A cold standby or hot/hot sites? No-one can answer your question as asked, you need to do the analysis work then you can ask a technology question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snapshots aren't backups. Period. To have proper DR plan you should follow so-called 3-2-1 backup rule which is "3 copies of data, two different formats, and one off-site copy".

https://knowledgebase.starwindsoftware.com/explanation/the-3-2-1-backup-rule/

https://www.veeam.com/blog/how-to-follow-the-3-2-1-backup-rule-with-veeam-backup-replication.html

https://www.backblaze.com/blog/the-3-2-1-backup-strategy/

If you run your workload in AWS "offsite copy" means non-AWS cloud.